# how to fix initializing nsmutable array strong with an expression of incompatible type void warning?

Tags: ios, ios7, nsmutablearray

I am using this code `NSMutableArray * nst = [navigationArray removeObjectAtIndex:navigationArray.count-1];` to remove some object in a nsmutablearray but i am getting "nsmutable array strong with an expression of incompatible type void warning" can any one help how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this

```
  NSMutableArray * nst = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:navigationArray ];
[nst removeObjectAtIndex:navigationArray.count-1];
NSLog(@"%@",nst);
```

This way, navigation array stays intact as it was, and nst is a new array with the navigation array content **and** the objects removed at the specific index.

OR

If you want to remove those contents straight away from `navigationArray`, then

```
[navigationArray removeObjectAtIndex:navigationArray.count-1]
```

This will make the objects removed from the `navigationArray` itself.
Xcode is complaining coz, `[removeObjectAtIndex]` doesn't returns an array and you are trying to assign `nst` to the return value of the method.

Hope could make u understand.